# Shape memory alloy fibers with low Young's Modulus?

Tags: elastic-modulus, actuator

I am wondering if there exist any species of shape memory alloy fibers with low Young's Modulus at room temperature, for an application I'm working on. So far I've played with Flexinol, but it is a bit too stiff. I know Nitinol has a Young's Modulus of ~30-40 GPa. I am wondering if there exist softer fibers - I'm interested ones that might be at around ~10 GPa, ~1GPa, and < 1GPa, if they exist.

Beyond other materials, is there any procedure to make Nitinol naturally softer?

Comment: Have you considered shape memory polymers?

Comment: I haven't.  Can you give more details?

Comment: Well, they are much softer than shape memory alloys. But after a quick search I wasn't able to find any reliable vendors, so they might not be your solution.

Comment: By the way, since NiTi alloys (Nitinol) require certain microstructure and composition for the shape memory effect to appear, you wont be able to make them softer than their typical values. There are other alloys based on aluminiun or copper which **might** be a little softer, but again you are bonded by their commercial availability.